# Is the activity id of an activity created in webform available as a token to then use in an email generated by the webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have a form that when submitted creates a new activity. I want to be able to send out an email from that same webform to a contact with a link to a second form that preloads the activity based on the activity id being in the url.

What would the token be (if there is one) that I could use to display the ID in the email generated from the webform? The activity id is not a field that I can display on the webform so cannot just copy the form key to get the token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version (7.x-4.20) has a token for that:
[submission:activity-id:?]
Replace ? with 1 for the first activity.

Comment: Thx Daniel - will get Gemma to upgrade as looks like the site testing only had 4.19 on it

Comment: Upgrade results in token being listed, testing has that token working. Thanks heaps

Comment: Should that read "Replace ? with 1 for the first Activity" rather than "Replace ? with 1 for the first contact"